# Adding a bitmap to a video

Tags: android, video, bitmap

How do I compress a bitmap to a video file with android. Like, adding the bitmap file to the video. I have a .png file which I decoded into a bitmap. Now, I want to add that bitmap to a video file so that when the video plays it also show the bitmap I added

Comment: Are you just looking for a link to somewhere that explains this, or help with some code? If the latter, please do include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the bitmap on top of the video when it is playing on your Android device, then the easiest thing is to display it in a separate view on top of the video, using a relative layout in your layout file, for example. This avoid CPU and battery consuming video manipulation.

If you actually want to add the image to the video so it is saved then one way to do this on Android is to use ffmpeg. There are several ways to use ffmpeg but one of the easier ones is to use a well supported ffmopeg wrapper, e.g.:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

This allows you use the standard command line syntax for the ffmpeg instructions themselves, which you will find is well documented and supported on the web. For example, the following covers adding an image into a video:

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html (look for ' overlay an image' near the bottom)

Note that adding the image is processing intensive, so you may quite likely find your device is not able to do this in real time - i.e. not able to add it while you are watching. If you have the luxury of being able to add the image first to the video and then watch it, then this may be more practical - you could even consider doing it on the server side after uploading the video, where you should have much more processing power.

If you must see the image and the video in real time then you may find a combination of the above approaches works for you - simply display the image over the video in realtime, and then add the image to the video afterwards before storing it.